# Get text of each dynamically created button

Tags: jquery

I want to get the text of a dynamically created button but seems like i'm doing something wrong.

```
$(document).on('click', '.online_users', () => {
        console.log($(this).text(););
    });
```

Comment: How are you creating the button?

Answer (score 0):

> Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own this .
> The value of this inside an arrow function remains the same throughout
> the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this
> in the closest non-arrow parent function.

Change the arrow function to a normal `function` if you want to use `this`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.online_users', function () {
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```